# Mitsubishi Melfa Basic VI - If..Then..Elseif..Endif syntax errors

Tags: robotics

Using Mitsubishi's RT Toolbox3 and Melfa Basic VI programming language, I am trying to get the syntax correct for an If...Then...Elseif...Endif statement.
I would like this robot to assess 3 external Inputs and based on their state run different Subroutines.  If none of these inputs are true I want the robot to go to a "Waiting" position, we'll label this position posXXX.

Here is what is currently running in this robot.  This script selects the proper subroutine but doesn't account for the condition when none of the inputs are true.  When I attempt to insert the "Else" Goto posXXX I get syntax errors.

```
 If M_In(11) = 1 Then *Box1
 If M_In(12) = 1 Then *Box2
 If M_In(13) = 1 Then *Box3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the script that resolved my question.

```
 *BoxEval
 Mvs posPostScan
 If M_In(10) = 1 Then
 GoSub *Box6
 Break
 ElseIf M_In(11) = 1 Then
 GoSub *Box1
 Break
 ElseIf M_In(12) = 1 Then
 GoSub *Box2
 Break
 ElseIf M_In(13) = 1 Then
 GoSub *Box3
 Break
 ElseIf M_In(14) = 1 Then
 GoSub *Box4
 Break
 ElseIf M_In(15) = 1 Then
 GoSub *Box5
 Break
 Else
 GoSub *BoxEval
 EndIf
```

Comment: One thing I would like to add to this answer is that Melfa Basic VI will only allow up to 8 nested conditions.  After that you get another syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I have used also Mitsubishi Roboter in my Bachelor Thesis and for going the position you should move the robot with remote control and then you should get position from Melfa Basic.It gets automaticaly from there.Then you should use that your position. I hope it will works.